# How to do SELECT SUBSTR(COLUMN1, 1, 3), * FROM TABLE1 in DB2

Tags: asp.net, sql, db2

In T-SQL you can do following

`SELECT SUBSTRING(COLUMN1, 1, 3), * FROM TABLE1`

But in DB2 I get the following error

> ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2] SQL0104N  An
>   unexpected token "," was found
>   following "".  Expected tokens may
>   include:  "FROM INTO".  SQLSTATE=42601

Is it possible to do this in DB2?

`SELECT SUBSTRING(COLUMN1, 1, 3), * FROM TABLE1`

**NOTE**

I am using asp.net to execute the query above

**EDIT**

I want to be able to grab everything but do a substring or a small calculation on one of the columns. I want to do a substring on one of the columns but I don't want to list out every column.

Comment: If you want `*` then you want all columns.  Do you want column1 or do you want all columns?

Comment: Can you try renaming the column using alias: SELECT Column1 as another_name, * FROM TABLE1

Comment: @maple_shaft I added an edit on what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated by maple_shaft your question doesn't really make sense, but the following should work (cannot try it right now though)

```
SELECT Column1, table1.* 
FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: I don't think that is DB2 specific, as far as I know you will need that syntax for every standard compliant database

Comment: No way, SQL Server will let you do this `SELECT AddressID, * FROM dbo.Address`

Comment: That's guanome's point - that syntax is not standard compliant, it will only work with SQL Server.

Comment: @michael That may be, but I still don't like DB2.

Answer (score 2):

Without the ing

```
SELECT SUBSTR(COLUMN1, 1, 3), * FROM TABLE1
```

Answer (score 0):

To select all the columns:

```
       SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1
```